# Discord Token invalid in heroku, in vscode working

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I keep getting invalid token in heroku, which cloned to git i checked my main.js in git its the same token I had in visual studio code, but the thing is heroku said that its invalid bot token but vscode's djs bot token works fine

I don't use config file, this is the error in heroku:

```
/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:133
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529108+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     const invalidToken = new DJSError(WSCodes[4004]);
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529109+00:00 app[Worker.1]:                          ^
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529109+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529109+00:00 app[Worker.1]: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529110+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.connect (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:133:26)
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529110+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:223:21)
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529110+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529111+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
2022-07-04T11:18:15.529111+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
```

this is in vscode:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJGHN.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to add more detail. Where does the token come from? Are you pulling it in from an environment variable? From a config file? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: there i edited it

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the code where you create a token. That looks like the library code that _complains about_ your token. Where do you try to _create_ a token in your own code?

Comment: In heroku, you need to provide its own token on your `modular settings` try to find it first then connect it on your bot thru `vscode`

Answer (score 0):

In Heroku there is an option to set environment variables just like a `.env` file. I dont know if you are already using that but if not that is probably where error came from. I dont think .env files even work in Heroku.

Hope this helps and have a nice day